# Pandas - Reordering columns by String contains concept and doing a compare between them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this.

```
ID    Name     Gender    Work     BBBB.FullName   BBBB.Sex    BBBB.Occupation
1     Test       M       MIS       Tester             M          GIS
```

And I want this to be re-ordered to this way,

1. ID always comes first
2. The first available column without starting with BBBB
3. The first available column starting with BBBB
4. The second available column without starting with BBBB
5. The second available column starting with BBBB

Expected output 1

```
ID   Name BBBB.FullName   Gender    BBBB.Sex    BBBB.Work       BBBB.Occupation
1    Test   Tester          M         M           MIS                 GIS
```

I want to compare the normal column with the next BBBB column and insert a column as True or False

**Expected Output 2**

```
ID   Name BBBB.FullName   Result_Name Gender    BBBB.Sex  Result_Gender   BBBB.Work       BBBB.Occupation  Result_Work
1    Test    Tester       False        M          M          True           GIS            MIS                False
```

Comment: Honestly, I think you could simplify your life immensely if you are willing to use suffixes and rename the columns of one frame before your merge. Sorting to get everything next to one another is simple and one groupby on the column stubnames gets the `Result` column for all pairs-wise groups. And using `'ID'` as your index is probably a decent idea at that point.

Comment: @ALollz a new bee to this language. So, I am experimenting and learning here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first separate the columns into those that start with `BBBB.` and those that don't

```
standard_cols = [x for x in df.columns if not x.startswith("BBBB.") and x != "ID"]
b_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith("BBBB.")]
```

We can turn these into pairs and then for each pair create a result column while constructing a list which captures our desired order to present the columns at the end

```
result_column_order = ["ID"]

for plain_col, b_col in zip(standard_cols, b_cols):
    res_name = plain_col + "_Result"
    df[res_name] = df[plain_col] == df[b_col]
    result_column_order.extend([plain_col, b_col, res_name])
```

Then to return in the desired order:

```
df[result_column_order]
```

Which returns the following

```
   ID  Name BBBB.FullName  Name_Result Gender BBBB.Sex  Gender_Result Work  \
0   1  Test        Tester        False      M        M           True  MIS   

  BBBB.Occupation  Work_Result  
0             GIS        False
```